# adding a new line in python - homework exercise for COP1000

Tags: python

ok so I have this homework for class, here is the specification:

*Write a program that uses a while loop to display the integers from 0 to 200 in increments of 25, all on one line separated by a single space. Then use a for loop and the range operator to display the same integers in descending order. See example output.

Example Output

0 25 50 75 100 125 150 175 200

200 175 150 125 100 75 50 25 0 *

Here is my code so far:

```
for number in range(0,225,25):
    print(format(number),end=' ')
for number in range (200,-25,-25):
    print(format(number),end=' ')
```

I need the second line of numbers, 200 through 0 to be added in a new line. I tried adding a comma at the end, the \n attribute, and nothing. I get errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: _"...and the range operator"_ - Those instruction material are wrong. range is a function not an operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension expression and `.join()` to accomplish your task:

```
>>> print(' '.join([str(number) for number in range(200, -25, -25)]))
200 175 150 125 100 75 50 25 0
>>>
```

**Explanation**

After the innermost expression us run - the list comprehension, A list of the numbers from 25 to 200 is created. We use `str()` to convert each one to a string

```
>>> [str(number) for number in range(200, -25, -25)]
['200', '175', '150', '125', '100', '75', '50', '25', '0']
>>>
```

We then use `' '.join()` to join the list of strings into one string, separating them by a space.

```
>>> ' '.join([str(number) for number in range(200, -25, -25)])
'200 175 150 125 100 75 50 25 0'
>>>
```

Lastly, the result of the entire expression is passed to `print()`, which displays the string

```
>>> print(' '.join([str(number) for number in range(200, -25, -25)]))
200 175 150 125 100 75 50 25 0
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is being caused by the `end=' '` you are including with your calls to `print()`. This replaces the normal newline at the end of each line with a space. This is good for you, because it puts spaces after each number you print. But at the end, you need a regular print with a default (newline) end-of-line marker:

```
for ...
    ...
print()  # Just this.
```

Comment: believe it or not this helped, the most. Now how many times and in how many formats I had to try the print() statement--HAH. you wouldnt believe it.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the strict wording of the assignment, your while loop can look like this:

```
i=-25
while i<200:
 i+=25
 print("%i "%i,end='')
print("\n")
```

And your for loop can look like this:

```
for i in range(200,-25,-25):
 print("%i "%i,end='')
```